# eingreifen + haben?

Tags: meaning, verb, conjunction

Mein Wörterbuch gibt `eingreifen + haben` für die Konjugation im Perfekt etc. Stimmt das immer, gibt es Umstände, unter deren das Verb eingreifen mit dem Partizip sein benutzt wird ?

Ich würde natürlich so sagen :

> Da die Polizei sofort eingegriffen ist, konnte Schlimmeres verhindert werden.

Ist es dann falsch ?

Comment: Meine Wörterbücher sagen das gleiche.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eingreifen wird - wie es das Wörterbuch vermuten lässt - immer mit *haben* im Perfekt konjugiert.
Regionale Sprachgewohnheiten mögen zum Trugschluss geführt haben, man könne auch mit *sein* das Perfekt bilden.

Anders beim Wort **einschreiten**. Dort wird das Perfekt mit *sein* gebildet:

> Ich bin eingeschritten.